# Draftsight 2016 Top Menus absent

Tags: cad

I upgraded to Draftsight 2016 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Now, when I start, there is no menu on the top.

[image: screen shot]
[Mouse hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxhg9.png)

Does anybody have an idea how to get the menu back?

Comment: See what happens when you mouse over the title bar (the dark gray one at the very top).

Comment: @Zacharee1 Nothing happens when I hover the mouse on top

Comment: What happens if you close all applications running in a window, then open a terminal and type `unity`. After that you can close the terminal and try to open your application and see if the menus are then there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped to me after upgrading to 2016 was copying the xml file from
`~/.config/DraftSight/12.1.2/Workspace/` to 
`~/.config/DraftSight/13.0.9/Workspace/`
as it was absent in the folder for the newer version (only files .original and .bak were there, probably backups not loaded by Draftsight).

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me. There seems to be a conflict with an older config file.
Go to ~/.config folder and rename the DraftSight folder (e.g. to DraftSight.bak) so that DraftSight creates a new config folder. The menus should then reappear when you open DraftSight, but you will have to go through the configuration options to set it up the way you had it before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the tools to show up again, you have to right click where the should be and select main, then choose the tool set you would like.  Hope this is helpful.